# What SHOULD happen if a negative value is passed to a method that returns the factorial of the value passed to it?

Tags: java

If I pass a negative value into a method that is supposed to return the factorial of the value what SHOULD happen?

Comment: depends how you want it to be handled.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hopefully an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

Comment: Your computer would explode. Or it would print some kind of error. Or it would work correctly. I think it would probably be the second or third one, but we can't rule out spontaneous silicon combustion.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Wishful thinking, you pyromaniac. More like your brain exploding from reading too many low-quality SO questions.

Comment: If it is well written, it would return Gamma(n+1): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: @Andreas [`HCF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire) **isn't** *literal*?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/10129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean what *should* happen, this is what it should return

Mathematically the factorial function is also defined as `gamma(n+1)=n!`,

there is also these relations `n*gamma(n)=gamma(n+1)` and `gamma(1/2)=sqrt(pi)`

Using these you can get the factorial for any non-integral negative number

for more information see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)